# Getting SublimeText2 to compile Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sublimetext

Really excited about using Typescript on the Mac however, even after a full day of troubleshooting, unable to get it to compile in SublimeText. Followed these directions (the first at the top) to install nodes and npm>

```
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814
```

Installed Typescript

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

Installed the syntax highlighting package for sublime

```
http://msopentech.com/blog/2012/10/01/sublime-text-vi-emacs-typescript-enabled/
```

Created a build file 'typescript.sublime-build as follows

```
{
"selector": "source.ts",
"cmd": ["tsc", "$file"],
"path": "/usr/local/bin",
"file_regex": "^(.+?) \\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\): (.+)$"
}
```

When I type $which node I get

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

When I type $which tsc I get

```
/Users/<username>/local/bin/tsc
```

BUT, whenever I try to compile even the simplest .ts file in SublimeText the first effort message I get is

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can anyone suggest further troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Have you tried `"path": "/Users/<username>/local/bin"?`

Comment: yes, in my .profile file added export PATH=/Users/<username>/local/bin

Comment: But, in the path for the `tsc` executable, you've still specified the path as being `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: on another install I get the error The node executable hasn't been found, you might want to set it in your typescript settings by adding the "node_path" key BUT my node_path IS correctly set in Preferences.sublime-settings "node_path": "/Users/<username>/local/bin" WTF?

Comment: thanks will try again changing "path" in build file to /Users/<username>/local/bin

Comment: Ok working BUT still get node not found when I launch Sublime...weird.  The node executable hasn't been found, you might want to set it in your typescript settings by adding the "node_path" key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with a little too.  It seems the PATH is quite different when trying to run commands directly from the build system than the terminal, and this is a cause of problems.

What I did as a simple workaround was just set my command to run a Bash script, i.e. in the sublime.project file have the command as..

```
"cmd": ["./build.sh"]
```

.. and then in the build.sh script in my project folder simply run the compiler, i.e..

```
#! /bin/bash
tsc --target ES5 foo.ts
```

Obviously this assumes foo.ts pulls in all the other project files so they get compiled (or you could [glob](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) for the files on the command-line seeing as you're running a Bash command).

This might be a quick and simple solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what my team mates do. Use Sublime Text for text editing with a grunt watch in the background compiling any files that change : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts